# Navigate hyperlink in yii

Tags: php, yii

I have created a hyperlink in my admin.php page as follows:

```
echo CHtml::Link('savepage','save');
```

This would mean that on clicking the given hyperlink it should perform the code given in actionSave() of my controller page.

Here is my code for controller-

```
actionSave()
{
echo 'hi';
}
```

But it gives an error-
Error 403
You are not authorized to perform this action.

If I change the "save" to "index" in my admin.php file, it is working well. How can I navigate to write my custom code for the link?

Answer (score 1):

in your controller you have to change the access rules. You have to register this action first.Index works for you because it is registered already.

```
public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update','Save'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),

        );
    }
```